# How to create a responsive canvas with absolute coordinates?

Tags: javascript, css, position, html5-canvas

I'm using the [Scrollpath plugin](https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath) to build a weird navigation in a website. It basically lets you draw a path using a canvas element and the scroll movement follows the path.

I would like to make it responsive, now, but I have really no idea where to start from.

To define the path you use directive in the form of `lineTo(200, 1000)`, which draws a line from the current or previous position to the one defined in the parameters.

The problem, I think, is that a point can be outside of the current viewport. So, how can I calculate its correct new position once I shrink the window?

Answer (score 1):

Research the `context.scale` transformation method on the canvas.

**The beauty of `context.scale` is that it allows you to expand/shrink the canvas without requiring you to change the original path coordinates.**

Since the Scrollpath plugin displays its content with a canvas you should be able to hack some responsiveness into the plugin using `.scale`.

Here are some links to get you started:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/html-canvas-guide/Translation,Rotation,andScaling/Translation,Rotation,andScaling.html

http://www.sitepoint.com/modernize-your-html5-canvas-game/